# adding nested OPC-UA Variable results in "String cannot be coerced to a nodeId"

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, opc-ua

### Error: String cannot be coerced to a nodeId

Hi,
I was busy setting up a connection between the Orion Broker and an PLC with OPC-UA Server using the [opcua iotagent](https://github.com/FIWARE-GEs/iotagent-opcua) agent.
I managed to setup all parts and I am able to receive (test) data, but I am unable to follow the tutorial with regards to adding an entity to the Orion-Broker using a json file:

```
curl http://localhost:4001/iot/devices      -H "fiware-service: plcservice"      -H "fiware-servicepath: /demo"      -H "Content-Type: application/json"      -d @add_device.json
```

The expected result would be an added entity to the OrionBroker with the supplied data, but this only results in a error message:

```
{"name":"Error","message":"String cannot be coerced to a nodeId : ns*4:s*MAIN.mainVar"}
```

### suspected Error

Is it possible that the iotagent does not work nicely with nested Variables?

### steps taken

- doublechecked availability of OPC Data:

  - OPC data changes every second, can be seen in Broker log
- reduced complexity of setup to only include Broker and IOT-agent

---

### additional information:

add_device.json file:

```
{ 
"devices": [
    {
        "device_id": "plc1",
        "entity_name": "PLC1",
        "entity_type": "plc",
        "attributes": [
            
            {
                "object_id": "ns*4:s*MAIN.mainVar",
                "name": "main",
                "type": "Number"
            }
        ],
        "lazy": [
        ],
        "commands" : []
  }
]
```

}

---

config of IOT-agent (from localhost:4081/config):

```
{
  "config": {
    "logLevel": "DEBUG",
    "contextBroker": {
      "host": "orion",
      "port": 1026
    },
    "server": {
      "port": 4001,
      "baseRoot": "/"
    },
    "deviceRegistry": {
      "type": "memory"
    },
    "mongodb": {
      "host": "iotmongo",
      "port": "27017",
      "db": "iotagent",
      "retries": 5,
      "retryTime": 5
    },
    "types": {
      "plc": {
        "service": "plcservice",
        "subservice": "/demo",
        "active": [
          {
            "name": "main",
            "type": "Int16"
          },
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "type": "Int16"
          },
          {
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "Int16"
          }
        ],
        "lazy": [],
        "commands": []
      }
    },
    "browseServerOptions": null,
    "service": "plc",
    "subservice": "/demo",
    "providerUrl": "http://iotage:4001",
    "pollingExpiration": "200000",
    "pollingDaemonFrequency": "20000",
    "deviceRegistrationDuration": "P1M",
    "defaultType": null,
    "contexts": [
      {
        "id": "plc_1",
        "type": "plc",
        "service": "plcservice",
        "subservice": "/demo",
        "polling": false,
        "mappings": [
          {
            "ocb_id": "test1",
            "opcua_id": "ns=4;s=test.TestVar.test1",
            "object_id": null,
            "inputArguments": []
          },
          {
            "ocb_id": "test2",
            "opcua_id": "ns=4;s=test.TestVar.test2",
            "object_id": null,
            "inputArguments": []
          },
          {
            "ocb_id": "main",
            "opcua_id": "ns=4;s=MAIN.mainVar",
            "object_id": null,
            "inputArguments": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of the iotagent-opcua repo, we have identified and fixed the bug you were addressing, please update your agent to the latest version (1.4.0)

If you haven't ever heard about it, starting from 1.3.8 we have introduced a new configuration property called "relaxTemplateValidation" which let you use previously forbidden characters (e.g. = and ; ). I suggest you to have a look at it on the configuration examples provided.